# Linking to Tensorflow as an external lib to C++ application

Tags: c++, tensorflow

Are there any supported alternatives to the approach presented on the Tensorflow [C++ guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/cc) that instead allows you to separately build Tensorflow and link your C++ application to it as an external library?

I've managed to compile libtensorflow_cc.so and link to it. But where can I get valid header-files. Just grabbing the header-files from source gives errors and I have to manually adjust the paths, which I'd rather avoid.

Comment: I use this https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc repository and add find_package(TensorflowCC REQUIRED) in cmake and there is no issue  with include file and not with lib target_link_libraries(project_name TensorflowCC::Shared)

Answer (score 1):

I use this https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc repository and add find_package(TensorflowCC REQUIRED) in cmake and there is no issue  with include file and not with lib target_link_libraries(project_name TensorflowCC::Shared)
or check that you include file path is correct to the path to you TF installation